# iOS: Getting an error regarding button tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

For some reason I'm getting an error when tapping a button that is hooked up to an IBAction. In my homeViewController a user performs an action, adding a new viewController to the navigationController, and within this view controller's view is a smaller view containing the **button**. I reveiwed my code, and looked through the inspector to see if I missed anything but nothing weird stood out.

Here's my added view controller's .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *popupView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blurredImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImage *blurredImage;

- (void)presentEventEditViewControllerWithEventStore:(EKEventStore*)eventStore;
- (IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender;;
- (IBAction)cancelEvent:(id)sender;
```

When I tap a button without linking the IBActions to either of them, no error. As soon as I link them, the app crashes and displays the following error:

[image]

P.S. I also received the following in a prior error (Before unlinking and relinking):

```
-[OS_xpc_connection cancelEvent:]:
```

UPDATE:

I load the bannerViewController the following way:

```
BannerPopUpViewController *BPV = [[BannerPopUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BannerPopUpViewController" bundle:nil];
    BPV.blurredImage = [self screenshot];
    [self.view.window addSubview:BPV.view];
```

Here is the first error I was referring to, courtesy of crashlytics:

[image]

But the one I keep getting, since I unlinked the action and relinked is the following:

[image]

Comment: That's not an error message. What does it say in the console?

Comment: - (IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender;; why 2 semicolon?

Comment: it may even depend on how you keep your controller in memory. If it's deallocated before the action is called, boom

Comment: @dimimpou Oops! Fixed the semi-colon. Built again and the app crashes with an exc bad access error.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I forgot to copy and paste it but it basically said that it didn't recognize the selector. I've also updated my answer, with more info. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You need to run it again and paste the error, it will help us determine "what" didn't recognise the selector?

Comment: If you're asking about a crash, you need to include any error messages you get. We need to know what the unrecognized selector was, and what object it was sent to, to have any chance of solving this.

Comment: Upvote to balance the downvote which haven't been explained by anyone.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble guys! Just updated my answer with the errors. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @AncAinu: There are several comments here pointing out a serious problem with the question. More importantly, [please don't vote just to offset other people's votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177805/should-one-upvote-if-the-downvote-was-unjustified-in-a-not-so-good-bad-question). Vote up if you think the _question is good_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell well, when I came the question seemed pretty well redacted for me. But maybe I arrived after the problem went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
[self.view.window addSubview:BPV.view];
```

The view is retained by its superview (the window in this case), but nothing is retaining the BPV view controller. Something needs to or it will get deallocated and then whenever any button is pressed it will result in a call to a destroyed object (turn on zombies to verify).

Retain BVP somewhere by saving it in a strong property of adding it as a chile view controller.

Comment: I ran it through instruments and you were right about the destroyed object. I went ahead and added the following line before adding the view, and everything seems to be working now! [self.navigationController addChildViewController:BPV];

Comment: Good stuff. p.s. please remember to tick answers that solved the problem ;-)